# Operators vs self invoked arrow functions inside jsx (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a question:
Do self invoked arrow functions have a bigger affection in performance than operators?

Here are two examples of the same action but one using self invoked arrow functions and the other with operators.

Example with Self invoked arrow functions

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        {(() => {
            if (props.show) {
                return <div className="message">Message</div>;
            }
        })()}
    </div>
);
```

Example with Operators

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        {props.show && <div className="message">Message</div>}
    </div>
);
```

I know that in these examples the operators example seems smaller, but I want you to focus in performance.
I want to know if there is a significant affection or if the usage of either could be considerer as equal.

Thank you!

Comment: Premature performance optimisation is the root of all evil. If you find a situation where performance is bad, profile it with the browser performance API. Otherwise don't worry about it and write maintainable code

Comment: @spirift Thank you for your answer, but for example what if the div with className message was a React component will it be unmounted and mounted again on every render (Im referring to the case where props.show doesn't change but other prop or  state do)?

Comment: In your first example the function is redefined each render cycle so whatever it returns ***will be*** a new returned value. If it is a React component then it will be a new component each time and mounted. The second example is the standard way to use conditional rendering. If the value of `props.show` is the same each cycle then the same JSX is rendered. If it is a React component it may rerender but it will remain mounted. I have no idea why you would approach conditional rendering with the first method at all. It seems very unreasonable to do so.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese thank you for your response. While waiting for responses I decided to make some test on this. I understand the part where you tell that as it is an arrow function it will be a new result on each render. The funny part is that on testing it doesn't unmount and mount a new Component. Look at this and tell me your comments please! https://jsfiddle.net/alanperezg/v04ycs5a/1/

Comment: When you toggle `state` it ***does*** unmount and mount the `Div` and `Div2` components. This is why you continually see "first render div" logs. When you toggle `state2` then both remain mounted and `Div` conditionally renders the `div` with message.